# Can't connect to a TFS Test controller from visual studio.

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013 Premium. I cannot connect to our TFS test controller, the message is "The server actively refused the connection".

I've disabled firewall on both client and server machines, and it does not appear to be a permission issue.

The exactly error message I am getting is:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it: [ip of machine].[port]

Any hints / suggestions or solution most welcome - and thanks!

Comment: Tried a telnet on ports 6910 6901?

Comment: What version of test controller is it?